# Does juju run on non-Ubuntu distributions?

Tags: juju

I have been experimenting with juju for an upcoming platform evaluation

Question I know I will be asked:
Is it possible to run juju on non-ubuntu distros?

Comment: In short i want to bring up and bring down non-ubuntu based AMI using juju.

Answer (score 10):

The juju client currently runs on Ubuntu, Debian, OSX, and Windows. For distributions that do not have Juju packaged it can be built from source.

As far a deploying it on a non-Ubuntu server, right now work is underway to enable support for CentOS, Debian, and Windows. Support for these operating systems is expected to land in future Juju versions, optimistically 1H of 2015.

Comment: How about the plans to port Juju to Centos? http://www.zdnet.com/article/canonical-juju-devops-tool-coming-to-centos-and-windows/

Answer (score 5):

Juju is not specific to EC2. it can work on OpenStack, bare metal, and other machine resource providers. At the moment it is specific to Ubuntu. Part of that is that, in the notion of cloud/utility computing, the distinction of the underlying OS is not as important versus the services offered/deployed on those systems. Additionally, **the charm definitions themselves are OS specific**. In future it will likely support additional operating systems, with a separate collection of OS-specific charms.

Comment: I wanted to invoke a particular AMI ID which is a CentOS or say Windows os AMI ,Will i be able to use Juju to start and stop from ubuntu platform.     default-image-id: ami-xxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

The client is pretty portable to any unix like system, at the moment its pure python minus a dependencies on libzk and libzk python bindings and twisted's openssl usage (cert checks).

If you want to try it via pip/easy_install (older version of juju atm)

```
pip install zkpython txzookeeper juju
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, the client also now runs on Windows as of juju 1.14, see https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/reference-releases