# Is juju specific to ubuntu OS on EC2

Tags: juju

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does juju run on non-Ubuntu distributions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138575/does-juju-run-on-non-ubuntu-distributions)

Is ubuntu juju specific to ubuntu OS on EC2. I mean can we use juju bootstrap default-series for other operating systems like centos etc.