# Is there an OpenShift charm?

Tags: juju

I saw that you have a charm for CloudFoundry. Is someone writing a charm to install OpenShift Origin (Red Hat's PaaS) say on free versions of RHEL like Scientific Linux or CentOS? I am interested in learning Juju but my software of interest is OpenShift Origin. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I've talked this over with some OpenShift developers and here's the current state of this.

- OpenShift requires the use of SE Linux, which is in Ubuntu but we're not sure if installing that from universe is sufficient enough to get OpenShift to work.
- Someone would need to get OpenShift running and working on Ubuntu.
- Someone would need to actually write the charm and test it in order to include it in the charm store.
- Juju only deploys to Ubuntu currently, someone would need to enable it to spawn off SL or CentOS instances.

  - [Does juju run on non-Ubuntu distributions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138575/does-juju-run-on-non-ubuntu-distributions)

If you or anyone is interested on working on this check out the [Juju mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/juju).